# How to populate observable with another observable and return observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm working on rxjs project and I am using json-server as database provider. I am stuck at getting one collection that I need to populate with another collection.

I have collection **Match** and collection **Tournament**.
Inside collection Match, I have tournamentId only, but my class Match also contains Tournament instance.

```
class Match{
    id:number;
    ...
    tournamentId:number;
    tournament: Tournament;
}

class Tournament{
    id:number;
    ...
    name:String;
}
```

I need 2 calls from db. First to get all tournaments, and then to get all matches.

I need to return *Match Observable* that has been populated with Tournament.

```
get(): Observable<Match> {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
      tournamentService.get().pipe(toArray()).subscribe(tournaments => {//tournaments = [torunament1, tournament2]
        super.get().pipe(map(x => { let m = new Match(x); m.populateTournament(tournaments); obs.next(m); return m; })).subscribe(() => {
          obs.complete();
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

**obs.complete()** is being called immediately, thus I end up with only one Match in observable that's created.
I'm trying to populate Match with Tournament in map pipe, and also send it as **obs.next(m)** there. I don't know if that is smart either.

**tournamentService.get()** and **super.get()** return Observables of *Tournament* and *unpopulated Match* respectively (JS {object} with same attributes).

How do I next() matches one by one and after they are all sent to subscriber call complete()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create your own observables, there are already existing operators you can use for that. I think mergeMap, switchMap and combineLatest all work here.

You should combine those two observables:

```
  get(): Observable<Match> {
    return combineLatest([super.get(), tournamentService.get()]) // Combine both Observables when both emit
      .pipe(map(([match, tours])=> { // Destructuring array of emitted values
        let m = new Match(match);
        m.populateTournament(tours);
        return m; // Return match combined with tournaments
    }))
  }
```

Comment: Acknowledged!
But still having problem. Tournaments is observable that emits only once (it's whole array of tournaments), since I need all tournaments in my populateTournament() method.

Comment: So what's the problem? You WILL get all the tournaments like this.

Comment: Left observable emits more times than right observable. super.get() is left. tournamentService.get().pipe(toArray()) is right. Since I dont need tournaments one by one, i need them all in array.

Comment: What I wanna say is that combineLatest is restricted by the observable that's emitted less. Since one observable is whole array (emitted once), other observable is restricted and only latest (for example 15th match) is emitted.

Comment: Managed it with withLatestFrom pipe.

Comment: combineLatest is not restricted, it will emit for each emission of both streams, but only after both have emitted at least once. It's just that in the example, every emission from stream `super.get()` happens before any emission from the other, so then it takes only the last one. Each emission after that will be seen in `combineLatest`. You can see that if you add a delay to the first one. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2jcqzd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I looked further into it, and it seems like I did something different, even though I do not see the difference. For my case, it only emitted last match. I will try to figure out what I did. Thank you very much, I appreciate your time!

Comment: For combining observables you can use zip, combineLatest, merge, concat and withLatestFrom. You can learn more in my video course: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with 'withLatestFrom' pipe also.

```
 get(): Observable<Match> {
    let matchesObs = super.get();
    let tournamentsObs = tournamentService.get().pipe(toArray());

    return matchesObs.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(tournamentsObs),
      map(([m, t]) => {
        let match = new Match(m as Match);
        match.populateTournament(t as Tournament[]);
        return match;
      })
    );
  }
```